# How to pass Artran lines in another tab

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm here to ask for help.

Description:

I am trying to send invoice lines to another tab,
I have a check, 
that is, a check box.

Example:

If the invoice has two lines, 
you must pass the two lines in another tab:
the problem is that they only send me one line, I have my code,
I will show them to them, I would like them to help me, I can't find a solution.

I attach the image

1: 
[image]

2: this is my control

[image]

3: FieldUpdate result

[image]

I'm doing with the event of

**"FieldUpdated"**

code

```
 protected void PEFEExternalTrade_SendOther_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        PEFEExternalTrade val = (PEFEExternalTrade)e.Row;
        if (val != null)
        {
            if (val.SendOther == true && Sendanothertab.Current == null)
            {
                ARInvoice ari = Base.Document.Current;
                if (ari == null) { return; }
                val.DocType = ari.DocType;
                val.RefNbr = ari.RefNbr;

                ARRegister arReg = PXSelect<ARRegister, Where<ARRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARRegister.refNbr>>, And<ARRegister.docType, Equal<Required<ARRegister.docType>>>>>.Select(Base, val.RefNbr, val.DocType);
                if (arReg == null && arReg.CuryID == null) { return; }

                Sendanothertab.Current = Sendanothertab.Insert();
                Sendanothertab.Current.RefNbr = val.RefNbr;
                Sendanothertab.Current.DocType = val.DocType;

                foreach (PXResult<ARTran> item in base.Base.Transactions.Select())
                {
                    ARTran arTran = item;
                    if (PEFEHelper.IsStockItem(arTran.InventoryID, cache.Graph))
                    {
                        InventoryItem cod = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, arTran.InventoryID);
                        FELines.Current = FELines.Insert();

                        FELines.Cache.SetValueExt<PEFEExtTradeLine.tranType>((object)FELines.Current, (object)arTran.TranType);
                        FELines.Cache.SetValueExt<PEFEExtTradeLine.refNbr>((object)FELines.Current, (object)arTran.RefNbr);
                        FELines.Cache.SetValueExt<PEFEExtTradeLine.lineNbr>((object)FELines.Current, (object)arTran.LineNbr);
                        FELines.Cache.SetValueExt<PEFEExtTradeLine.inventoryID>((object)FELines.Current, (object)arTran.InventoryID);
                        FELines.Cache.SetValueExt<PEFEExtTradeLine.identification>((object)FELines.Current, (object)cod.InventoryCD);
                        FELines.Cache.SetValueExt<PEFEExtTradeLine.qty>((object)FELines.Current, (object)arTran.Qty);
                        FELines.Cache.SetValueExt<PEFEExtTradeLine.totalAmt>((object)FELines.Current, (object)arTran.CuryTranAmt);
                        FELines.Cache.SetValueExt<PEFEExtTradeLine.unitPrice>((object)FELines.Current, (object)((!arReg.CuryID.Equals("USD")) ? CalcUSDUnitAmount(cache, arTran.CuryUnitPrice, ((val != null) ? val.EtCuryRate : null) ?? 1m, (val != null) ? arReg.CuryID : null) : arTran.CuryUnitPrice));
                    }
                }
                Sendanothertab.Current.EtUsdTotal = CalcUSDTotal(FELines.Select());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Tibu, I think you can duplicate the tab and based on the visible expression do hide and show of new tab.

Comment: check your iskey fields to make sure the keys are not limiting your records. Also if the 2 grids are using the same DAC type you will need to update both where statements to limit the records displayed. And another to try is the insert. Set the keys before inserting (Ex: the RefNbr and DocType fields if they are keys)

Comment: thanks guys if it works I was doing the logic badly, but I still thank you for your response to each one.